# how to understand the C++ syntax of this code line?

Tags: c++, opencv

What's the meaning of `&I.operator IplImage()`, it seems unfamiliar in C++ syntax.

```
Mat I;
Ptr<IplImage> piI = &I.operator IplImage();
```

Comment: On `I`, call `operator IplImage()` (cast to `IplImage`), take the address of the result, and construct a `Ptr<IplImage>` from it.

Comment: apart from your current problem, *avoid* anything that has IplImages in it. they did away with the arcane c-api way back in 2010, and so should you.

Answer (score 1):

"operator IplImage" is in fact the full name of type conversion operator. So "I.operator IplImage()" converts I from type Mat to type IplImage. At last, piI points to the address of the resulting IplImage. It is equivalent to:

```
    Ptr<IplImage> piI = &static_cast<IplImage>(I);
```

Comment: thanks! It is so clear. And I found function in Mat class:
    operator IplImage() const;

another question, the implementation of thsi conversion should be defined by Mat class rather than IplImage class, am I right?

Comment: @4simplicity Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a user of OpenCV but I can give you an overview of what the code is doing:

`Mat I;`
Creates a `Mat` object given the name of `I`.

Let's cut the next line up:
`Ptr<IplImage> piI` seems to be a smart pointer for `IplImage`.

`&I.operator IplImage()` converts the `Mat` object into that of `IplImage` by taking its address.

Answer (score 0):

this

```
operator IplImage();
```

is a call of a conversion operator that converts an object of type `Mat` to an object of type `IplImage`.

And this expression

```
&I.operator IplImage()
```

denotes the address of the converted object.

However it seems that the code should not be compiled because operator & is applied to a temporary object of type IplImage returned by the conversion operator function `operator IplImage()`.